# Django - Create a custom id

Tags: python, django, primary-key

I know Django auto generates a ID for my model with a primary_key

And I also know that if I want to generate a custom id I should do:

```
id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

But how can I change this so the id would look like this `YYYYMMDDXXXXXX` ?

Where:

```
YYYY = year

MM = month

DD = day

XXXXXX = random number
```

Comment: Any particular reason you really need to do that and not just have a date field on the model?

Comment: One use case could be an app that generates quotations that need a quote number. Sure, it doesn't have to be the PK but it's nice to have something that is unique

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a reason why you should make a id like that but yeah you can do it. Just create a small function to generate id and pass it to your field.

```
import datetime
from uuid import uuid4
def create_id():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    return str(now.year)+str(now.month)+str(now.day)+str(uuid4())[:7]
```

Then in model field

```
id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, default=create_id, editable=False)
```

Remember to pass function object as parameter not a callable.

Comment: @EduardoSatler be warned though that creating more than one user a day using the pattern you specify has a chance (although likely slim) of generating the same ID and your DB will reject it causing an exception. In that case you should retry a certain amount of times until you find a non-used one.